# PHP readfile() of external URL

Tags: php, readfile

Can I use external URLs in readfile()?

```
    header('Content-type: application/pdf');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.$file.'" ');
    //header('Content-Length: ' . filesize("http:...z/pub/".$file.'.pdf'));
    @readfile("http://...z/pub/".$file.'.pdf');
```

Comment: Try it and/or [RTM](http://php.net/readfile): "A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the fopen wrappers have been enabled." ;-)

Comment: Should I do 'exec("wget $url -O $filename")'?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The PHP manual on [`readfile`](http://us.php.net/readfile) states:

> A URL can be used as a filename with this function if the [fopen wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) have been enabled. See [fopen()](http://us.php.net/fopen) for more details on how to specify the filename. See the [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php) for links to information about what abilities the various wrappers have, notes on their usage, and information on any predefined variables they may provide.

As an alternative you can also use `file_get_contents`:

```
echo file_get_contents("http://...z/pub/".$file.'.pdf');
```

Comment: In both solutions there is some problem with filesize or something else, because is not working.

Comment: @user583311 What seems to be the problem?

Comment: @user583311: 'not working' is pretty vague. At least remove the error suppressing operator (`@`) so that you can see (and tell us) WHY it is not working

Comment: It downloads a file with 300b, and the original has 300Kb. And the script works if the URL is local. So, must be something about external URL.

Comment: What are the contents of this file? I'm pretty sure you can open it in text editor and see PHP's error message.

Comment: As I say before, It works with a local file. No erros, as far I can see.

Comment: That's why I'm asking about contents of the file when the url is external. Just open it in notepad, and see what these 300 bytes are.

Comment: This is a bad idea.  By using `file_get_contents()`, you buffer the entire content in memory and then force it to be echoed out.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, according to the [readfile](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) page:

> A URL can be used as a filename with
>   this function if the [fopen_wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen)
>   have been enabled. See
>   fopen() for more details on how to
>   specify the filename. See the
>   [Supported Protocols and Wrappers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php)
>   for links to information about what
>   abilities the various wrappers have,
>   notes on their usage, and information
>   on any predefined variables they may
>   provide.