# java - send a file to client by file URL without download on the server

Tags: java, download

In my web application I have a link which, when clicked, invokes an external web service to retrieve a download URL for a file.

I need to send back to client the file which is beyond this URL, instead of the download URL retrieved from the web service. If possible, I would also like to do it without having to download the file on my server beforehand.

I've found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6086231/9864539) about a similar task, but which used PHP with the `readfile()` function.
Is there a similar way to do this in Java 8?

Comment: Would be useful to see your controller method and the way `request`, `response` is handled. Otherwise you could use `URLConnection` read line by line and send to response output stream, eg https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/readingWriting.html

Comment: @Aivaras unfortunately I use a framework which does not expose directly the servlet request/response. I've tried to add some details to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you doesn't even want to handle that file you should answer the request with a redirect (eg HTTP 301 or 302). If you want to handle the file you should read the file in a byte buffer and send it to the client which would make the transfer slower.
Without seeing your implementation so far, this is my best suggest.

Comment: I did not think about redirection, which is exactly I need in my case. I've tried to perform a redirect to the URL retrieved from the web service and it works, thank you very much!