# PHP readfile() URL issue

Tags: php

I have a url like this:

```
http://r16---sn-4g57kn6e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?&quality=medium&signature=797C0FEB1961E6226294D5FC19BC0CD28657975C.1E745D852200D14B706F0EBF9EA8762680374564&itag=43&mv=m&ip=84.19.165.220&ipbits=0&ms=au&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&mt=1390347607&id=8b92b07ff9cd9862&key=yt5&fexp=942502,916626,929305,936112,924616,936910,936913,907231,921090&upn=cMPazwtmyZU&sver=3&sparams=id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&expire=1390371882&type=video%2Fwebm%3B+codecs%3D%22vp8.0%2C+vorbis%22&fallback_host=tc.v12.cache5.googlevideo.com&title=Requiem+For+A+Dream+Original+Song&title=Requiem For A Dream Original Song
```

The problem is that the `readfile()` function produces a error cause of the special characters (bad request).

If i use `urlencode()` it ruins the url even more.

How can i handle this?

Comment: Awesome track BTW. Now I have to drink myself to sleep again though

Comment: This may help [PHP readfile() of external URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752389/php-readfile-of-external-url) :)

Comment: Oh yeah it is. I listen to it since 4 hours (repeat function). It's very good while coding :D

Comment: Nope that does not help. My question has nothing todo with that persons one.

Comment: There is an awful lot of repetition in your URL. Have you tried to make it more compact?

Comment: How should i do that? What you mean with "more compact?" This values are required otherwise the link becomes invalid. That's YouTUbe lol

Comment: Don't urlencode the whole string, just the song title?  Have you tried using file_get_contents instead?

Comment: I encoded everything except the http://. Yes file_get_contents produces exactly the same problems. I also removed the title for testing purposes and got the same result.

Comment: @Michael You're encoding it wrong.  As we have all said, do not encode everything.  The point of URL-encoding is that you can use an arbitrary string in the context of a URL.

Comment: How should i do that? I can't manually create url. I need to work with the URL that i get (like in the above example).

Comment: The issue here is that you can't scrape Youtube using file_get_contents or cURL for that matter. At the very least, you would need to create a `bash script` to scrape the video from Youtube. This type of protection is in place for a particular reason and you'll never achieve the proper result attempting this.

Comment: That is not true. Once again: The problem is the format of the URL, nothing else!

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to `urlencode()` the data in you use in the querystring.  In your post, you have not escaped the last variable.  Do not `urlencode()` the whole URL.. that would not be proper.

http://r16---sn-4g57kn6e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?&quality=medium&signature=797C0FEB1961E6226294D5FC19BC0CD28657975C.1E745D852200D14B706F0EBF9EA8762680374564&itag=43&mv=m&ip=84.19.165.220&ipbits=0&ms=au&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&mt=1390347607&id=8b92b07ff9cd9862&key=yt5&fexp=942502,916626,929305,936112,924616,936910,936913,907231,921090&upn=cMPazwtmyZU&sver=3&sparams=id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&expire=1390371882&type=video%2Fwebm%3B+codecs%3D%22vp8.0%2C+vorbis%22&fallback_host=tc.v12.cache5.googlevideo.com&title=Requiem+For+A+Dream+Original+Song&title=Requiem For A Dream Original Song

I would just use `http_build_query()` instead.

```
echo 'http://r16---sn-etc' . http_build_query(array(
    'ip' => 84.19.165.220,
    'ipbits' => 0,
    // etc.
    'title' => 'Requiem for a Dream'
));
```

Comment: Sorry i can't follow you. Can you please post a example? As i said above i encoded everything except the http://. Even without the titel it is not working.

Comment: @Michael Right, you're encoding more than you should be.

Comment: @Michael see my updated answer for an "automatically built" url / query string. And Brad : +1 for pointing to `http_build_query()`.

Comment: @Michael Of course you can build the URL yourself...  And, you needn't build the entire thing, just the parts you need.  Leave the rest as-is.

Answer (score 0):

Combining things I had in my original answer, plus some of the ideas in Brad's answer, I offer the following solution

```
<?php
$url='http://r16---sn-4g57kn6e.googlevideo.com/videoplayback?&quality=medium&signature=797C0FEB1961E6226294D5FC19BC0CD28657975C.1E745D852200D14B706F0EBF9EA8762680374564&itag=43&mv=m&ip=84.19.165.220&ipbits=0&ms=au&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&mt=1390347607&id=8b92b07ff9cd9862&key=yt5&fexp=942502,916626,929305,936112,924616,936910,936913,907231,921090&upn=cMPazwtmyZU&sver=3&sparams=id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&expire=1390371882&type=video%2Fwebm%3B+codecs%3D%22vp8.0%2C+vorbis%22&fallback_host=tc.v12.cache5.googlevideo.com&title=Requiem+For+A+Dream+Original+Song&title=Requiem For A Dream Original Song';
$cleanUrl = parseQuery($url);
$data = getData($cleanUrl);
echo "file read in OK\n";

function parseQuery($url) {
  preg_match('/(https?:\/\/[^?]+\?)(.*)$/', $url, $rawQuery);
  preg_match_all('/([^=]+)=([^&]+)&/', $rawQuery[2], $queries);
  $qArray = array_combine($queries[1], $queries[2]);
  $newUrl = $rawQuery[1] . http_build_query($qArray);
  return $newUrl;
}

function getData($url) {
$useragent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1";

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $useragent);
$data = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
return $data;
}
?>
```

This basically involves the following steps:

1. Take the initial URL, and split it into "stuff before the `?`, and stuff after"
2. The "stuff before" is untouched; the "stuff after" is split into two array - the keys and the values of the query ("everything up to `=`", and "everything up to `&`")
3. These two arrays are then combined into a valid query string using (from Brad's answer) the `http_build_query` array
4. Finally, I use `curl` to fetch the file (just because I know it better than `readfile()`).

It appears to work for me. Let me know if it doesn't work for you...

Comment: No it has nothing to do with the useragent. The problem is the format of the url. `curl_exec(): 23 is not a valid cURL handle resource`